# How to declare subtype with additional properties in JSDoc for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

How can I use JSDoc comments to declare to the TypeScript compiler that "type X has all the properties of type Y, as well as these other properties"?

Given:

```js
/**
A base type with one property.

@typedef {object} Base
@prop {string} name
*/

/**
A subtype that adds a second property.

@typedef AugmentedBase
@type {Base}
@prop {number} age
*/

/**
 A function declared to return AugmentedBase, so name + age.

 @returns {AugmentedBase}
 */
const shouldReturnAugmentedBase = () => {
  return {name: 'a', age: 3}
}
```

When:
I typecheck this by running:

```js
tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit index.js
```

Then:
I expect no errors when checking with TypeScript.

But:
In fact, it appears to ignore the property added by `AugmentedBase` and treat it as only `Base`, judging by this error:

> error TS2322: Type `'{ name: string; age: number; }'` is not assignable to type `'Base'`.
>
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and `'age'` does not exist in type `'Base'`.

Note that it is griping that the object literal does not match `Base`, in spite of a `@returns {AugmentedBase}` annotation!

Why:
I am writing JavaScript in Visual Studio Code and wish to make the most of its TypeScript linting.

Comment: Have you tried @implements http://usejsdoc.org/tags-implements.html ?

Comment: @GrahamPHeath It looks like `tsc` doesn't handle either `@implements` or `@interface`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not in a way that `tsc` will actually clue into.

`tsc` (at least as of 2.9.2) only supports attaching `@property`s to a `@typedef` name when the base `@type` is declared as `object` or `object[]`.

You can see it explicitly skipping any `@property`s when you use the `@typedef {NotObject} MyType` syntax at [this point in compiler/parser.ts:parseTypedefTag()](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d7713f430551e3f4b315d2be8350d2ce88b9e502/src/compiler/parser.ts#L6814).

If you try to get clever and instead put the `@type` decl after all `@property` decls, like:

```
/**
 @typedef MyType
 @property {string} x
 @type NotObject
*/
```

then the TypeScript compiler will successfully parse out all the properties, only to intentionally ignore them in favor of saying "the type of `MyType` is just straight-up `NotAnObject`" at [this slightly later point in compiler/parser.ts:parseTypedefTag()](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d7713f430551e3f4b315d2be8350d2ce88b9e502/src/compiler/parser.ts#L6839-L6841).